# Draggable image inside text editor, prevents text input

Tags: javascript, html, css, quill

Im working on a website which has a Quill JS texteditor, additionally I have used interact JS to put an image on the website and make it resizeable/draggable.

the idea was that the user can drag the image anywhere on the page, and it will compliment the text.

However the problem is that when I allow the image to be put anywhere on the page , it "blocks" the user from entering any text to the QuillJS editor.

```js
     var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
                modules: { toolbar: toolbarOptions},
                theme: 'snow'
            });
```

```css
    #drag-1{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            min-height: 6.5em;
            padding: 0.1%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
            
            border:2px solid;
            z-index:1;
        }
    #editor {
        z-index:0;
    }
    
    .draggable{
        z-index:1;
    }
    #imageCanvas
    {
    height:600px;
    width:96%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    transform: translate(-8%, -80%);
    float: right;
    z-index:-1;
    
    
    }
```

```html
 <div id="container">
                    <div id="editor">
                       </div>
  
            <div id = "imageCanvas">
                <img src = <?php echo '"data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($imgData['image']) . '"'; ?>  alt="Image preview..." target = "self" id ="drag-1" class ="draggable"/>
               
                </div>
```

there is a tonne of code for the interact JS so I wont paste it -, im not sure how relevant it is here?! I tried to straight up input an image inside the  editor class/id , and the image went "behind" the text editor.

Ive tried changing the z index of each element , for example when I make the z index of the image 1 , and the editor -1 , if I reload the page , the image will flicker for a fraction of a second and then the editor cover it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the Image CSS positon to absolute to make it appear on top!

I was setting the position of the images class as absolute, rendering the rest of the textbox useless.